# Keeping zero padding in stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream, zero-pad

I have a memory area containing characters that represent different hex words. When I print them I would like to keep all characters but with my current code zero padding in non-zero numbers is stripped off. For example if I have in memory characters `0000` it outputs `0000` but if I have `0001` it outputs `1`. I am currently using a stringstream, but have also tried using a character array to construct a string (see comments):

```
stringstream ss;
char* data_ptr = sets[set_index]->get_block(block_index)->get_word(word_index);
for (int d = 0; d < 2 * bytes_word; d++){
    ss << *(data_ptr + d);
}
data = ss.str();

//char* data_ch = new char[2 * bytes_word];
//char* data_ptr = sets[set_index]->get_block(block_index)->get_word(word_index);
//for (int d = 0; d < 2 * bytes_word; d++){
//  data_ch[d] = *(data_ptr + d);
//}
//string data(data_ch);
//delete[] data_ch;
```

From this I tend to thing that the stripping might actually be done when I pass the string to the stdout, I use `cout << data;`, since my debug mode shows the contents of the string in both cases to contain all 0's. If this is so how could I solve it?

**EDIT - Solved**
As posted in accepted answer had to used `setfill()` and `setw()` which I wasnt aware of. This didnt solve the problem at first because `data_ptr`points to characters, I simply took out the for loop and used `atoi(data_ptr)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using

```
 std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << data;
```

Cheers!

Comment: This solves the problem partiallly, now the output for 0 is `0000` and for 1 it is `001` instead of `0001`, any clue why?

Comment: Well that's weird, you would have to edit your original question showing a bit more of the code (what does "sets" contain and how are you loading values to it, for example) or a sample snippet that can be ran.